# wicket and CompoundAuthorizationStrategy

Tags: java, wicket

I'm not sure if I got a good idea of this strategy working. In my app I have 2 seperated login forms, one for ordinary users and second one for admin only (dont ask why, thats the way it is :) )

What I'm trying to achive is proper redirection. In my WebApplication class I have:

```
init() {
//...ommited some not related code
    CompoundAuthorizationStrategy compoundAuthorizationStrategy = new CompoundAuthorizationStrategy();
    IAuthorizationStrategy membertPageAuthStrategy = new SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy( MemberTemplatePage.class,
            HomePage.class )
    {
        @Override
        protected boolean isAuthorized()
        {
            //here's my way to define if authorization is completed
        }
    };

    IAuthorizationStrategy adminPageAuthStrategy = new SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy( AdminTemplatePage.class,
            AdminLoginPage.class )
    {
        @Override
        protected boolean isAuthorized()
        {
            //here's my way to define if authorization is completed
        }
    };

    compoundAuthorizationStrategy.add( membertPageAuthStrategy );
    compoundAuthorizationStrategy.add( adminPageAuthStrategy );

    getSecuritySettings().setAuthorizationStrategy( compoundAuthorizationStrategy );
//...
}
```

MemberTemplatePage is template for logged in user page, while AdminTemplatePage is same thing for admin. 
Now I though that, with this chained auth strategy, I'll be redirected to HomePage when I enter MemberTemplatePage unauthorized and to AdminLoginPage when I enter unauthorized to AdminTemplatePage, but I'm keep redirected to AdminTemplatePage. 
Couldn't google anything on CompoundAuthorizationStrategy, and it seems to be best choice for me. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I know about RoleAuth~ but thats not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@roby You're probably right, after some search in wicket source I make this change in my code:

```
init() {
//...ommited some not related code
CompoundAuthorizationStrategy compoundAuthorizationStrategy = new CompoundAuthorizationStrategy();
IAuthorizationStrategy membertPageAuthStrategy = new SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy( MemberTemplatePage.class,
        HomePage.class )
{
    @Override
    protected boolean isAuthorized()
    {
        if ( /* user not authorized */ )
            {
                throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException( HomePage.class );
            }
            return true;
    }
};

IAuthorizationStrategy adminPageAuthStrategy = new SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy( AdminTemplatePage.class,
        AdminLoginPage.class )
{
    @Override
    protected boolean isAuthorized()
    {
        if ( /* user not authorized */ )
            {
                throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException( AdminLoginPage.class );
            }
            return true;
    }
};

compoundAuthorizationStrategy.add( membertPageAuthStrategy );
compoundAuthorizationStrategy.add( adminPageAuthStrategy );

getSecuritySettings().setAuthorizationStrategy( compoundAuthorizationStrategy );
//...
}
```

And it works just like I wanted it to :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code from CompoundAuthorization

```
public final boolean isInstantiationAuthorized(Class componentClass)
{
    int size = strategies.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        IAuthorizationStrategy strategy = strategies.get(i);
        if (!strategy.isInstantiationAuthorized(componentClass))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It will check the class you are trying to instantiate against each strategy, if all of the checks succeed instantiation is authorized. So it probably succeeded during the regular user authorization check and then attempts admin authorization and gets redirected to the admin login page.